# XML/XSL Replacing a space with <br/>

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to clean up the readability of my code. Using v1. Any help on what I'm doing wrong is greatly appreciated.

XML code that I have:

```
    ...
    <trusted-servers>mark mike sally</trusted-servers>
    ...
```

I want it to display the following way:

```
    mark
    mike
    sally
```

Originally, it's displaying in this way using (`<xsl:value-of select="trusted-servers"/>`):

```
    mark mike sally
```

What I have tried is:

```
    <xsl:value-of select="string-length(substring-before(trusted-servers, concat(' ', trusted-servers, '<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<br />]]></xsl:text>')))" data-type="string"/>
```

But it throws an error saying that unescaped character `<` isn't allowed. I tried taking out the `<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<br />]]></xsl:text>` part and replacing it with `<br/>` but still have the same error. I'm clueless in any other ways of doing it.

Comment: What is the target format, plain text or HTML or XML?

Comment: Targeted for HTML. I'm using xsltproc to parse it into a HTML file. So this is written in an .xsl file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, `<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">`should be avoided as much as possible!

Since you're using XSLT 1.0, the best solution is to write a template which will recursively replace the first space encountered by a `<br>`, for instance:

```
<xsl:template match="trusted-servers" name="replace-space-by-br">
    <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, ' ')">
            <xsl:variable name="head" select="substring-before($text, ' ')"/>
            <xsl:variable name="tail" select="substring-after($text, ' ')"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$head"/>
            <br/>
            <xsl:call-template name="replace-space-by-br">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$tail"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming xsltproc you have http://exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/index.html so you can do

```
<xsl:template match="trusted-servers">
  <xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize(., ' ')">
    <xsl:if test="position() > 1"><br/></xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

where you declare `xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"` on the `xsl:stylesheet`.