# How to <br> when atrribute's value contains a ";"?

Tags: xslt, contains, line-breaks

I have an XML with attribute `<reason>`, it could contain more than one reasons, the reasons are separated with `;`:

```
<reason>reason1;reason2</reason>
```

In my XSL, I would like to check the value, if the value contains `;` I would like it to print it to another row. (as below)

```
reason1
reason2
```

I tried to use `contains` to detect the `;` as below, but it doesn't work.

```
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test = "contains('./Reasons',';')">
    <td>test_1</td>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
   <td><xsl:value-of select="./Reasons"/></td>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XML/XSL Replacing a space with <br/>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20959843/xml-xsl-replacing-a-space-with-br)

Comment: You say "I have an XML with attribute `<reason>`" but in XML terminology an attribute `reason` looked like `<element reason="...">...</element>` so it rather seems like you have an element named `reason`. As for your code, if you want to check that the element selected by the XPath expression `reason` contains a semicolon, use `contains(reason, ';')`. Your attempt `contains('./Reasons',';')` checks whether the string literal `'./Reasons'` contains a semicolon. Splitting up the values into several tokens can be done in XSLT 2 or 3 with `tokenize(reason, ';')`.

Comment: Show more XML and XSLT template where choose is exist?